# Android Native Application is Crashing on few mobiles (Oppo, Mi) when integrated Sqlcipher, why?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

Recently we released an android application with sqlcipher, maximum it's working on all android mobiles except few mobiles such as Oppo, Mi....etc

even the app is running on few oppo mobiles

App not running on the following configuration (Oppo)
(Model no A37f, ColorOdVersion - V3.0.0i, Android Version - 5.1.1, Processor - QualcommMSM8916Quadcore, Ram 2GB)

App running on the following configuration (Oppo)

(Model no A1601, ColorOdVersion - V3.0.0i, Android Version - 5.1, Processor - Octacore, Ram 4GB)

In the above two configurations except processor everything is same.

used the following one

```
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.1.3@aar'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the latest version `4.2.0`?

Please try with the latest version as they have fixed this issue.
Ref: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/438

Comment: Please let me know how to integrate 4.2.0 on android studio. thank u

Comment: You can update your version in gradle. 
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.2.0@aar'

Comment: if i give like this, it's throwing could not resolve net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.2.0@aar

Comment: you can refer following reference. Might need to sync with online mode.
Ref: [Here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should need to use latest version of it.
Please try with latest version of `4.2.0`.

It will work.

Comment: tried with new version tooo, though it doesn't work...Thank u

Comment: @Kruti Kamani Are you confirming it did work for you? Because in this thread there are people also saying that version 4.2.0 won't work either https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-for-android-ver-4-1-3-crashes-on-android-5-1-1/3657/4